# Issue in remotely running maven command

Tags: java, maven, remote-access

I have written a batch script to call mvn commands remotely. But an error as shown below is displayed

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

Batch script is given below:

```
pushd \\IP\eclipse\workspace\Example_Automation
call "\\IP\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\mvn" clean
call "\\IP\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\mvn" -Dtestfile=exampleTest.xml test
popd
pause
```

Comment: Does the host machine have access to ip?

Comment: Have you tried to set `M2_HOME`?

Comment: Why are you using such an archaic version of Maven?

Answer (score 0):

You may have set up your environment correctly for your interactive user shell to behave correctly if you run `mvn`. However, your script may get a new environment with different settings. Precede the call to run `mvn` with setting your Maven home, such as:

```
set M2_HOME=...your Maven home path...
```

*Your Maven home path* may be something like `E:\Programs\apache-maven-3.2.3`.